# What would a minimal example for a choropleth map in Mathematica look like?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, geospatial

What would a minimal example for a [**choropleth**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map) map in Mathematica look like?

I can read in a ESRI Shapefile using `Import`, but do not know how to work with the imported result.

Comment: [This](http://mathgis.blogspot.com/2009/11/make-us-county-thematic-map-using.html) post,from _LunchTime Playground, Fun with Mathematica_,  on **How to make a US county thematic map with Mathematica** might be of interest?

Comment: Nice link, Tom.  Here's another, @Karsten:  Michael Shreiber's demo, ["Color-coded country comparison"][1] 

  [1]: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ColorcodedCountryComparison/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Graphics[
   {
    ColorData["ThermometerColors"][
                            Rescale[CountryData[#, "GDPPerCapita"], {100, 50000}]
                                  ] /. HoldPattern[Blend[___]] -> Yellow, 
    CountryData[#, "Polygon"]
   } & /@
   CountryData[]
]
```

[image]

And why the replacement? If there are no data of the required type for a given country CountryData returns Missing["NotAvailable"], causing `ColorData`, and its underlying `Blend` function not to return a specific RGB value. I replace this unevaluated `Blend` with the color Yellow.

Comment: Nice example, interesting use of ColorData and Rescale. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just for reference, here some tips for working with ESRI Shapefiles. `CountryData` does not provide county-level data for Germany (the administrative unit is called "Kreis"), which is why I wrote my own `KreisData` function. The shape file I used can be [downloaded for free](http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz1/abgabe/d-karten-zip/vg2500_lamgw.zip), however there are terms of use to consider.

The `KreisData` function is then created as follows:

```
shp = Import["C:/TEMP/map/VG2500/vg2500_krs.shp", "Data"];
polys = "Geometry" /. First[shp];
ags = "RS" /. ("LabeledData" /. First[shp]);
names = "GEN" /. ("LabeledData" /. First[shp]);
area = "SHAPE_AREA" /. ("LabeledData" /. First[shp]);
KreisDataRules = 
  Dispatch[MapThread[
    Rule[#1, #2] &, {ags, Transpose[{polys, area, names}]}]];
KreisData[tag_String, "Polygon"] := First[tag /. KreisDataRules];
KreisData[tag_String, "Area"] := Part[tag /. KreisDataRules, 2];
KreisData[tag_String, "Name"] := Last[tag /. KreisDataRules];
KreisData[] := ags;
```

With this function, and the example code by Sjoerd C. de Vries, a map of Germany is created thus:

```
renderMap[scheme_String] :=
  Graphics[{ColorData[scheme][
        Rescale[KreisData[#, "Area"], {3.63067036816521*10^7, 
          3.08469540395003*10^9}]] /. 
       HoldPattern[Blend[___]] -> Yellow, KreisData[#, "Polygon"]} & /@
     KreisData[]];
Manipulate[renderMap[s], {s, ColorData["Gradients"]}]
```

[image: Result with "GrayTones" color scheme]

Answer (score 3):

A throw on *Minimal* in the [code golf](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-golf/info) sense:

```
Graphics@Function[f,{Hue[f[#,"Area"]/10^7],f[#,"Polygon"]} &/@ f[]]@CountryData
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because I cannot resist a Code Golf competition with belisarius:

```
Graphics[{Hue[i~#~"Area"/10^7],i~#~"Polygon"}~Table~{i,#[]}&@CountryData]
```

(for the same result)

Answer (score 0):

@Karsten W.: unfortunately your shp file is not longer available. I tried a similar one (vg250_0101.utm32s.shape.ebenen\vg250_ebenen\vg250_krs.shp) from the same source but I got the error message "Transpose: the first two levels can not be transposed" from your function KreisDataRules. And since I did not really understand what your code does, maybe you can help.
I try to produce a thematic map on a Kreis level, where the colouring shows the number of tourists in our city, if necessary also 0.
I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering any question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Volker, this way to use stackoverflow is to write this as a new question and link to this. However, in order to help you, I would need a link to the shape file you want to use.

Comment: @KarstenW.: thank You so much for Your offer, but I was able to solve my problem using  some of your code elements. However I will open a new question about the following steps: using there graphics objects as GeoGraphics so that I can use Mathematica's functions like GeoRegionPlot, GeoBubbleChart etc.