# Mathematica North America map

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mapping, visualization, gis

How would you render a map such as this one within Mathematica? (e.g. one with US states and Canadian provinces colourable separately?) http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/archive/1/18/20071029031002%21North_America_map_coloured.svg

I've tried to import the SVG paths and build polygons (with an approach based on http://mathgis.blogspot.com/2009/11/make-us-county-thematic-map-using.html) but they look much less nice than the curves in the linked SVG. The built-in databases didn't appear to have shapes for US states and Canadian provinces: only countries.

Thanks!

PS: the aim of this is to be able to make choropleth maps for state/province data (i.e. to colour states/provinces according to some data related to that state/province)

Comment: Related: [choropleth map in mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468271/what-would-a-minimal-example-for-a-choropleth-map-in-mathematica-look-like).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use .kml or .kmz files to get a list of states/provinces and polygons for their outlines. For example for the USA you could use [this file](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/us_states.kml). To extract the polygons you could do something like this

```
usa = Import["http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/us_states.kml", 
  "Data"];

transform[s_] := StringTrim[s, Whitespace ~~ "(" ~~ ___ ~~ ")"]

polygons = Thread[transform["PlacemarkNames" /. usa[[1]]] -> 
  ("Geometry" /. usa[[1]])];
stateNames = polygons[[All, 1]];
```

Then polygons will be a list with elements `"state name" -> Polygon[points]`. The function `transform` is just a helper function to get the PlacemarkNames from the .kml file in the desired format (in this case stripping "(year)" off the end of the names).

Using these polygons you can then use `FaceForm[]` to colour the individual polygons. Suppose we have a list of data of the form `"state" -> value`, e.g.

```
data = Thread[regionNames -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length[regionNames]]];
```

Then we can create the map according to

```
colourf = ColorData["Temperature"];
element[value_, poly_] := GraphicsGroup[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[colourf[value]], poly}]

Graphics[{element @@@ Transpose[regionNames /. {data, polygons}]}]
```

Which looks like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

What about using some image processing on existing map images? This is just a prototype workflow. There are quite a few things to explore with data integrated from Wolfram]Alpha and image processing  in Mathematica. You can play we these in more detail. I did not really try to use the population data and color the map accordingly, but I think it is possible. Function MorphologicalComponents[...] detects and indexes states regions between the borders.

```
map = WolframAlpha["Illinois", {{"Location:USStateData", 1}, "Image"}]
```

[image]

```
bmap = Binarize[map, .7]
```

[image]

```
dmap = ColorNegate@Dilation[ColorNegate@bmap, .75]
```

[image]

```
MorphologicalComponents[dmap] // Colorize
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's pretty neat! I was really hoping for a workflow which I could extend to make choropleth maps (e.g. display state/province data via colour) which would be hard with this approach...

Comment: @nicolaskruchten You might find some of the information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7468271/616736) useful.

Comment: Thanks! I have seen that but what I need is a map of North America with states/provinces identified. This is not available in the built-in databases, and I don't have any shape files, only SVG files.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to outline the states begins with using the GeoGraphics feature:

```
GeoGraphics[
{
EdgeForm[Black],
Polygon[CountryData["UnitedStates", "AdministrativeDivisions"]]
}
GeoBackground -> None,
GeoProjection -> "Mercator"
]
```

[image]